# How is asynchronous I/O libraries like Boost.Asio implemented behind the scenes?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, boost

> How is asynchronous I/O libraries like Boost.Asio implemented behind the scenes?

I wonder how these asynchronous libraries are implemented. I am a little familiar with the **Windows API**, but haven't noticed any specific API calls flagged as asynchronous.

Is the asynchronous functionality implemented in code on top of the operating system API, and if so, how is this done? Or do the library just call asynchronous API operations?

I know the concepts of event loops and I/O threads handling the execution of callbacks. Could there be a single thread spawned for each **asynchronous** operation, waiting for the **synchronous** operation like `socket.recv()` to complete, and thereafter executing the provided callback?

Comment: Boost is available in source code. Open the code and read. It will do you a lot of good! And if you see a particular construct which is unclear, ask specific question.

Comment: I didn't knew that. Can this code be read by a student, or is professional expertise required?

Comment: Also, could you describe in a few sentences which of my approches (if any) is taken?

Comment: Nicolas, start reading already :) You will see if the code can be read by a student. This is the only way for student to become professional - by reading other professionals code!

Comment: Heh, I see. But how did the first professional become a professional then ;) - just joking.... Thanks!

Comment: Asynchronous IO does not work with threads. you tell your OS to do some IO action, but to free the thread to do somehting else. you also tell your OS how to notify you when the IO is done. this can be by signaling an event object, interupting sleeping thread or use a polling object like IOCP in windows ir epoll on linux.

Comment: on WinApi, reading files asynchonously is done by opening a file handle with `CreateFile` wih asynchronous node and putting an `OVERLAPPED` pointer in `ReadFile`, for example